# \startuml command in doxygen with PLANTUML_JAR_PATH

Tags: doxygen, plantuml

I am using plantuml to generate to UML figures and have a problem about the comments style.

Steps to reproduce my problem:

I create a file called mainpage.dox and write these contents:

```
/** \mainpage Sender class
 * Sender class. Can be used to send a command to the server.
 *  The receiver will acknowledge the command by calling Ack().
 *  \startuml
 *    Sender->Receiver  : Command()
 *    Sender<--Receiver : Ack()
 *  \enduml
 */
```

Then, I create doxyfile to set output optimized java or C#, has_dot and PLANTUML_JAR_PATH. The UML figure could be generated after running doxygen.

However, there is no any contents of mainpage and warning message when I change comment style into C#:

```
/// \mainpage Sender class
/// Sender class. Can be used to send a command to the server.
/// The receiver will acknowledge the command by calling Ack().
/// \startuml
///   Sender->Receiver  : Command()
///   Sender<--Receiver : Ack()
/// \enduml
///
```

But the main page is generated (Show the text below) when I remove the uml comments

```
/// \mainpage Sender class
/// Sender class. Can be used to send a command to the server.
/// The receiver will acknowledge the command by calling Ack().
```

Does \startuml have to use C style comments? Thanks for any suggestion.

This is my DoxyFile: http://pastebin.com/hjEFz8b0

EDIT:

I just tested again with another style of comment. \startuml is working with this style

```
/*! \mainpage Sender class
Sender class. Can be used to send a command to the server.
The receiver will acknowledge the command by calling Ack().
\startuml
Sender->Receiver  : Command()
Sender<--Receiver : Ack()
\enduml
*/
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm afraid you found a bug.

In the meantime I've published the following fix for it:
https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/commit/4df52916170bb81179697d0fa78c7d81fd95415f

Comment: Thanks to fix this bug.